# Automatic vs manual WebApi client generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, autorest

I am planning to create a client for existed Restful API and choosing rather to do it manually or automatically using such tools as Autorest or Swagger codegen.
What is pros and cons of both ways?
Are there any disadvantages of generating client automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, I don't think there is no breaking reason why you shouldn't use a code generater.

I propose that you have a look into the open issues for the generators (e.g. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues)

In general one thing comes in to my mind on external codegeneration. If you use style cop or any other coding style validator, it can be that the generated code doesn't match your defined coding style rules.

Just give it a try, you save much time.

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues contains not only issues but also feedback, questions, feature tracker, etc.

Comment: One can also use customized templates to meet different coding style requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to do this in C# you might want to take a look into Swashbuckle, that contains a swagger generator and the Swagger-UI.

For the client side you can use a tool such as AutoRest to generate C#, Java, etc, code for the client out of the swagger.json.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing C# clients or TypeScript clients with jQuery or Angular 2+, an alternative [ASP.NET Web API Client Generators](https://github.com/zijianhuang/webapiclientgen) may be more handy, less overhead than swagger toolchain during SDLC.

Answer (score 0):

Please give [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) a try. For C#, please follow the insruction below to generate API clients (.NET Core) in 3 steps:

1. Download the Java JAR (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/6.0.0/openapi-generator-cli-6.0.0.jar)
2. Rename the JAR as "openapi-generator-cli.jar"
3. Run the following command to generate an C# .NET Core API client for the Petstore API (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/3_0/petstore.yaml):

Mac/Linux:

$ java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -g csharp-netcore -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/3_0/petstore.yaml -o /var/tmp/csharp-netcore/

Windows:

$ java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -g csharp-netcore -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/3_0/petstore.yaml -o C:\tmp\csharp-netcore